# Reading MongoDB from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I face some peculiar issues,

- I have created a new collection and inserted some data into that from my Node.JS program but those collection doesn't appear in the mongo console. But when I read data from Node.Js it displays data
- Also I'm not able to read the existing collections and its data.

Am I missing anything? I'm using mongojs native driver to connect to Mongo.

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct database in mongo console? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Got it worked !! I have connected my console into different data base's port.

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer and accept it. :)